# "System.NullReferenceException" while filling dictionary with keys from an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, exception, dictionary, null

I have a problem in my code. here is the problematic snippet. The reading of the line does work, but at the point where he should fill the zeilendict with the keys and the values, he throws an "System.NullReferenceException" and I dont know why.

Did I do something wrong in the loop, or is the dictionary not right iniziated? or is arr1 empty?

```
Module Module1
Public zeilendict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Public insertdict As Dictionary(Of String, String)
Public Sub einlesen()

    Form1.ID = 0
    Form1.OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Form1.path = Form1.OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Form1.OpenFileDialog1.Dispose()

    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Form1.path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs)

    Dim ersteZeile = sr.ReadLine()

    Form1.arr1 = ersteZeile.Split(New Char() {";"c})

    sr.Close()
    fs.Close()

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Form1.arr1.Length - 1
        Form1.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Form1.arr1(i))
    Next

    Dim i1 As Integer

    For i1 = 0 To Form1.arr1.Length - 1
        zeilendict.Add(Form1.arr1(i1), 0)
    Next
```

Comment: you are not creating `zeilendict` and `insertdict` just declaring it, you will need to use `New`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not initiated your dictionary. There for adding items will give a NullRefException

Try adding:

```
Public zeilendict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = new Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
```

or set this as first line in your method:

```
zeilendict = new Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
```

Also do this for the other Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Add the keyword "New" to your declartion to initialize your dictionary:

```
Public zeilendict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
```

Otherwise it will only be declared but contain nothing, therefore the Exception when you try to add something.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zc73115%28v=vs.90%29.aspx